# Como obter dados de uma tabela em um site?

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que captura os proxies e portas desse site, para o programa obter as proxies eu usei expressão regular e htmlagilitypack...
Porém, como obter as portas? Visto que por expressões eu acabaria pegando numeros que não são proxies?

```
var search = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table");
        foreach (HtmlElement ele in search)
        {
            HtmlElement h2 = ele.Parent.FirstChild;
            if (h2.InnerText == "IP Address")
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Columns.Add("IP");
                table.Columns.Add("Porta");

                HtmlElement tableBody = ele.FirstChild;
                foreach (HtmlElement tableRow in tableBody.Children)
                {

                    HtmlElement _IP = tableRow.FirstChild;

                    HtmlElement _Porta = _IP.NextSibling.NextSibling;

                    DataRow row = table.NewRow();

                    row[0] = _IP.InnerText;

                    row[1] = _Porta.InnerText;

                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Olá @AlanAssis, bem vindo ao **SOpt**. Aproveite para fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para perceber melhor como funciona o site. Quanto à sua questão, pode postar o código que já tem?

Comment: Pronto @JoãoMartins

Comment: Quais os resultados que obtém com esse código? Pode dar alguns exemplos?

Comment: Nenhum haha, quando o código chega em "HtmlElement tableBody = ele.FirstChild"
Ele chega no valor errado, to tentando arrumar...